# Topology induced by a norm

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, normed-spaces

I came across the notion of a $\textit{topology induced by a norm}$.

If $(X,\Vert\ . \Vert)$ is a normed space w.r.t a norm $\Vert\ . \Vert: X \to \mathbb{R}$. Most sources define the topology $\tau$ on $X$ induced by $\Vert\ . \Vert$ as the sets $U \subset X$ open w.r.t. the metric $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $d(x,y) = \Vert x - y \Vert$.

But would I be correct in assuming that an equivalent definition would be $\tau = \{\Vert\ . \Vert^{-1}(U) \mid U \subset \mathbb{R}\ \textrm{open} \}$?

Comment: Note that the preimage of U would be a subset of $X\times X$, not $X$

Comment: Wouldnt you be applying the norm preimage to a real number (representing the norm) and trying to get the original set which has that value as a norm back out? Or am I misreading?

Comment: We know topologies are induced by metrics.  But norms induce metrics too. So a norm should imply a metric, which then implies a topology. Assuming all other criteria are met.

Comment: @BrianMoehring My bad, didn't pay enough attention

Comment: I think you only get a neighborhood basis at $0$ with this definition, but that uniquely determines the topology, so in a sense it is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your version and $\Bbb R$ with norm $|\cdot|$, the set $(-3,-2)\cup(2,3)$ would be open, but $(2,3)$ not.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your sets $U'=\|\cdot\|^{-1}[U]$ are always symmetrical in that $x \in U$ implies $-x \in U'$. Not all open sets will obey that. These sets will give the open balls around the origin for $U$ that are symmetric around $0$, but not all other translated balls.

Answer (score 0):

In fact $\tau$ is the topology induced by $\{ \lVert. \rVert^{-1}(U): U\subseteq \mathbb{R} \ \ \text{is Open} \ \}  $

Comment: @Brian Moehring Thankyou. I edited it